# OBJ C login with php and mysql real_escape_string returns null

Tags: php, mysql, objective-c, null

I've a problem with login code in obj c with php and mysql. I send with POST strings to php script, and select row from mysql with and if its correct(or incorrect) i encode with json array with string YES or NO. It always return null. What's wrong with that?

```
- (IBAction)login:(id)sender {
login = _loginText.text;
password = _passwordText.text;

NSString *connect = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"&login=%@&password=%@",login,password];
NSData *postData = [connect dataUsingEncoding:NSASCIIStringEncoding allowLossyConversion:YES];
NSString *postLength = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d", [postData length]];

NSMutableURLRequest *request = [[NSMutableURLRequest alloc]init];

[request setURL:[NSURL URLWithString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"http://myurl/ilog.php"]]];
[request setHTTPMethod:@"POST"];
[request setValue:postLength forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Length"];
[request setValue:@"application/x-www-form-urlencoded" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Current-Type"];
[request setHTTPBody:postData];
NSURLConnection *con = [[NSURLConnection alloc]initWithRequest:request delegate:self];
NSLog(@"%@", connect);

if([self confirm])
{
    NSLog(@"PASS");
} else {
    NSLog(@"NO");
}
}

-(bool) confirm
{
NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://myurl/ilog.php"];
NSURLRequest *requests = [[NSURLRequest alloc]initWithURL:url];
NSData *_downloadedData = [[NSMutableData alloc]init];
_downloadedData = [NSURLConnection sendSynchronousRequest:requests returningResponse:nil error:nil];
NSString *json_string = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:_downloadedData encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
NSMutableArray *array = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:_downloadedData options:NSJSONReadingMutableContainers error:nil];
NSString *string = array[0];
NSLog(@"%@", array);
if ([string isEqualToString:@"YES"])
{
    return YES;
}
return NO;
}
```

And PHP code:

```
<?php 
$connection = mysqli_connect("host", "user", "pass","db");
$pass = "NO";
$login = mysqli_real_escape_string($connection, $_POST['login']);
$password = mysqli_real_escape_string($connection, $_POST['password']);
$sql = "SELECT * FROM Users WHERE Login='$login' and Password='$password'");
$result = mysqli_query($connection, $sql);
if(mysqli_num_rows($result)==1)
{
$pass = "YES";
}
$arr = array($pass);
echo json_encode($arr);
mysqli_close($connection);
 ?>
```

Comment: Add error reporting to the top of your file(s) right after your opening `<?php` tag 
`error_reporting(E_ALL); ini_set('display_errors', 1);` see if it yields anything.

Comment: Add `or die(mysqli_error($connection))` to `mysqli_query()` if still no errors, then it's your `obj c` code failing, which I won't be able to help you with.

Comment: still no errors but thanks for try:)

Comment: You're welcome. I +1 to see if someone else will pick up on it, good luck. Cheers

Comment: Why bother with the whole array business? all you're doing is sending back  a yes or no. Just send that plain string, ditch all of the json infrastructure.